# Which cloud storage providers allow you to query text files line-by-line?

Tags: sql, api, cloud, storage, dropbox

I have a large number of .txt files that I currently query line-by-line from my external HD using FileSeek. The results of each query appear on the FileSeek application.

I'm looking for a cloud storage service that will hold all of my text files and allow me to search for individual lines via either a search within my account on the website or (if it exists) allow me to create a REST API that I can connect to my bubble.io application.

I've attempted to use BigQuery for this but it requires CSV files or SQL files. Given that I have 1000s of text files and it would take a long time to convert them, I was hoping there was a cloud product that allowed me to query the text files line-by-line like I currently do with FileSeek.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be very appreciated!